# How to debug JS Script in external html file with content loaded do main div - Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

I am learning a little about SPA.
I wanted to make a simple page where in the main **index_test0.html** file I have a "content" div.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Navigation Example</title>

    <!-- The CSS theme for the site. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css" />

    <!-- Include jQuery. -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Navigation links -->
    <div id="navbar">
      <a href="#index_test1">Home</a>
      <a href="#index_test2">About</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Dynamic content will be placed here by JavaScript. -->
    <div id="content"></div>

    <!-- The JavaScript code for dynamic behavior. -->
 
  </body>
</html>
<style>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

/* Style the navigation bar links.  */ 
#navbar a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;

  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* Give the user an affordance that each link is clickable. */
#navbar a:hover {
  border-color: black;
}

/* Style the active page link. */
#navbar a.active{
  border-color: gray;
}


</style>

<script>

// This script implements simple routing by loading partial HTML files 
// named corresponding to fragment identifiers.
//
// By Curran Kelleher October 2014

// Wrap everything in an immediately invoked function expression,
// so no global variables are introduced.
(function () {

// Stores the cached partial HTML pages.
// Keys correspond to fragment identifiers.
// Values are the text content of each loaded partial HTML file.
var partialsCache = {}

// Gets the appropriate content for the given fragment identifier.
// This function implements a simple cache.
function getContent(fragmentId, callback){

  // If the page has been fetched before,
  if(partialsCache[fragmentId]) {

    // pass the previously fetched content to the callback.
    callback(partialsCache[fragmentId]);

  } else {
    // If the page has not been fetched before, fetch it.
    $.get(fragmentId + ".html", function (content) {

      // Store the fetched content in the cache.
      partialsCache[fragmentId] = content;

      // Pass the newly fetched content to the callback.
      callback(content);
    });
  }
}

// Sets the "active" class on the active navigation link.
function setActiveLink(fragmentId){
  $("#navbar a").each(function (i, linkElement) {
    var link = $(linkElement),
        pageName = link.attr("href").substr(1);
    if(pageName === fragmentId) {
      link.attr("class", "active");
    } else {
      link.removeAttr("class");
    }
  });
}

// Updates dynamic content based on the fragment identifier.
function navigate(){

  // Isolate the fragment identifier using substr.
  // This gets rid of the "#" character.
  var fragmentId = location.hash.substr(1);

  // Set the "content" div innerHTML based on the fragment identifier.
  getContent(fragmentId, function (content) {
    $("#content").html(content);
  });

  // Toggle the "active" class on the link currently navigated to.
  setActiveLink(fragmentId);
}

// If no fragment identifier is provided,
if(!location.hash) {

  // default to #home.
  location.hash = "#index_test1";
}

// Navigate once to the initial fragment identifier.
navigate();

// Navigate whenever the fragment identifier value changes.
$(window).bind('hashchange', navigate);
}());
</script>
```

After pressing the buttons from the menu, the content from the external files should be loaded.
However, I wanted to check if I can load both static content in this way, as in the **index_test1.html** file:

```
<html>
    <div id="internal_content">
        HOME
    </div>
<html>
```

as well as dynamic content, the script of which is stored in an external file - index_test2.html:

```
<html>
    <div id="internal_content"></div>
<html>
    
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("internal_content");
c.innerText = "ABOUT";
</script>
```

I think it works.

The problem is that I can't see these 2 external files in my Chrome debug window, so I can't debug the script in **index_test2.html**.

What should I do?. Or should I make it differently?

Answer (score 0):

you can see those javascript request in development tool's network tab. search specific file name (js file name) on filter. then click request. It will take you to specific js file and can do debug.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am closer, but when I clicked main.js file I see not my script but something else and I can't debug this.

[link](https://imgur.com/e7Tq79O)

Comment: After loading this file. Press ctrl+shift+f in developer tool and search 'KasperskyLab'.You will get file in rest there you can do debug